# Compress the images on uploading using Google drive REST API

Tags: java, google-drive-api, image-compression

I am trying to upload some images to my google drive using Google [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads) for java clients.

Basically my images are of about 4 - 5 MB size, how can I compress the image size while uploading?

Something similar the google photos application compresses the images to standard size while uploading the images.

Comment: what have you tried so far!!. actually we can compress images using multiple methods, you want to compress the image, on client end while uploading.. then API needs to have some application installed like google uses the libraries in PICASA..

Comment: Fragment revised a bit

Comment: Did you succefully manage to upload a photo to drive @mpsbhat ?
 i'm stuck trying to figure out how to do this, i can create an empty "drawing" file but can't upload my content